# Reference Request: Discrete Dynamical Systems for Undergraduates

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation

I am looking for a primer text in discrete dynamical systems for an undergraduate level of understanding in mathematics. I have taken introductory courses in numerical analysis and computational math, so I can understand basic proofs for quadratic convergence and whatnot. However, I'm still new to a lot of this stuff, and eager to apply such systems to mathematical modeling. Thus, I am asking if anyone knows a solid book that a beginner-intermediate mathematician can really learn a lot from.

I know that Boston University's Robert Devaney has a couple textbooks- would that be a good start? If so, which of his texts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with Devaney's [*A First Course In Chaotic Dynamical Systems: Theory And Experiment*](http://math.bu.edu/people/bob/books.html#first-course).

Try also [*Invitation to Dynamical Systems*](http://www.ams.jhu.edu/~ers/invite/) by Scheinerman, which is freely available and also as a Dover book.

Comment: Thanks- I just checked it out. +1 that it comes with a solution manual.